# Hooke's law for atom-to-atom energy well can't be right

Tags: fluid-dynamics, potential-energy, spring, physical-chemistry, atoms

[Hooke's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hooke%27s_law) says that the potential energy between two atoms is, $V(x)$, for two atoms with distance $r_1-r_0$ is $\frac{1}{2}kx^2$.

At room temperature and at equilibrium, water would have an equilibrium constant $k$ of $1$. The covalent bond of water is $497 \;kJ / mol$. One $mol$ of water is $0.055\; gm$. According to Hook's law, it would take only $27\; kJ$ of energy to compress $1\;gm$ of water into almost nothing.

Even in the case of a non-singularity, a volume in the neighborhood of a singularity would not require more energy on compression, and would essentially allow the neutrons to pass right next to each other, overcoming $1\; mol$ of strong nuclear force. The limit as a diameter of a neighborhood approached zero compressing $0.05\; gm$ of $H_2O$ could not possibly go from nominal to $\frac{1}{2}kx^2$. It would take $27\; kJ$ to break all the bonds in $1\;gm$ of water.

This can't be right, right? Note that Hooke's law is used in molecular dynamics.

---

Even if this doesn't account for O-O bonds, the same can be applied to a solid crystal diamond lattice with C-C bond strength of $347$ and similar proportions.

---

And if I'm totally wrong, does that really mean it would only take $\frac{1}{2}kx^2$ of energy to push a nucleus directly up against another nucleus?

Comment: "At room temperature, in equilibrium, water would have an equilibrium constant K of 1."  What?  Why?

Comment: my chemistry might be a bit rusty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hooke’s Law is a first-order linear approximation and is only valid over a small range of deformation. You cannot use it to conclude anything about the forces between atoms or molecules outside of this range - except that, as your example shows, these forces cannot be linear over their whole range.

Comment: is there anywhere I can find how much this deviates from the actual value over temp/distance/etc or a more accurate approximation? would calculating such a thing require actually calculating QFT forces with the standard model and stuff?

Answer (score 1):

Chemical bonds apply at the atomic level  and the potential tying atoms and molecules up to liquids and solids cannot be approximated by the potential of a spring, it is too complicated for that. The atoms and molecules are in orbitals, which allow spaces where positive and negative electromagnetic forces allow for bonding,( [see for links this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/262280/if-a-water-molecule-is-neutral-how-do-water-molecules-attract-one-another-by-el/262315#262315) of mine for example,) and the potentials are very complicated.

[Any symmetric in x potential](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/154297/quantum-simple-harmonic-oscillator-interpretation/188141#188141) can [be expanded in a series](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022369768901583)  and the first term will be a $x^2$, (that is why the harmonic oscillator is so useful in quantum mechanical studies) but the coefficients on the terms determine how many of them should be included in order for a calculation to be correct within errors.